# How to prevent combobx dropdown event in border click

Tags: combobox, visual-foxpro, foxpro, visual-foxpro-9

In Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9 Combobox control is placed to form.

Its style is

> 0 -Drop-down combo box, which includes a list box and an edit box

[image]

When clicked in border combobox dropdown event occurs.

To reproduce, create an empty form, add combobox control to it, run it using Ctrl+E and click exactly in border.

How to prevent this so that dropdown event occurs only if clicked in selection button in right side?
Or how to select mouse coordinates or something other in drowdown event to determine, is border or selection button clicked?

I tried to set combobox border style to None, but border click still raises dropdown event.

Comment: I just want to point out having a click anywhere in a combo drop the combo open seems to be the Windows standard. I tried in several different applications and in all of them, which I clicked anywhere in the combo, it dropped open. So I think you should consider whether you really want non-standard behavior.

Comment: User wants to click in combox text area to enter text. Mistakenly it clicks in border, only 1 pixel away from text area. Dropdown menu opens in this case. This is very confusing. I fixed this by adding `IF (MCOL(0,3)-this.left)<(this.width-20) 
  NODEFAULT
  RETURN
ENDIF
` to dropdown event handler. It has hard coded button width 20 pixels. Has dropdown button width 20 pixels always?